# Azure Logic Apps - Office 365 Connector - Use individual user accounts

Tags: office365, azure-logic-apps

I have the following scenario:

I'm trying to automate creation of Events in Calendars in Office 365 exchange with Azure Logic Apps.

Right now I'm using a generic account that would send meeting invites to the users. It gets sent to Sales Rep and the Customer.

I would like to modify that so - the meeting request appears to come from the sales rep in question - rather than the generic account.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can accomplish that strictly with the Office 365 Connector in Logic Apps as this connector and its features are designed to operate on behalf of a single user whose credentials and grant of your LA are stored as a secure API Connection in Azure.

The automation you're looking to implement sounds like something CRMs are precisely built for. Within the Logic Apps, there are connectors for Microsoft Dynamics, Salesforce, Mailchimp and more.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, the reason for this work is to cover the shortcomings of Hubspot CRM which does an extremely poor job at integrating with Office 365. I know with Exchange web service SOAP web server it was possible to pass in "From" field (and as long as that account had permission to Send on behalf of other account - you could use a generic account to send on behalf of other accounts. There isn't a "From" field in the connector in Logic apps.

Comment: aha! In that case, another approach that you can take might be to use Microsoft Graph (or REST) API (which will allow sending emails/creating calendar events on behalf of users in your tenant), Azure Functions and Logic Apps.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can create a ARM template that deploys a Logic Apps  Office 365 exchange connector to a given resource group.

2) This ARM template would have parameters for username and password required for the API connection

3) As part of your onboarding (e.g. sign up web site, installer MSI), you would need to request username and password for this user (and sometimes give permission to logic apps to access the resource).

4) Step 3 would create the API Connection with the required authorization, then the logic app could be deployed pointing to that API connection.
[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-deploy-azure-resource-manager-templates) gives you the basic of ARM provision for Logic Apps.